# SQL max and null

Tags: sql, null, max

I am trying to get the `null` value in the `USAGE_START_DATE` column.

So far, what is i got is the unique max records of those with value in the `USAGE START DATE` column, and could not find any the records with `nulls` in the `USAGE START DATE`.

I already tried `ISNULL`, `COALESCE`, `NVL`, `NZ`.

I got 2 tables: linked by Reservation_id.

```
ReservationID   Usage Start Date
1                01/01/2001 00:00:00
1                02/01/2001 00:00:00
1                03/03/2001 00:00:00
2                NULL
2                NULL
```

So far with my current code: Here is what I got:

```
ReservationID    Usage Start DAte
1                03/03/2001 00:00:00
```

Here is what I want:

```
ReservationID     Usage Start Date
1                 03/03/2001 00:00:00
2
```

Thank you!!!

To simplify my code:

```
SELECT distinct RENTAL_DETAILS_VW.RESERVATION_ID,  
RENTAL_DETAILS_VW.USAGE_START_DATE,
FROM BYNXFLEET_BI.RENTAL_DETAILS_VW, WILLOW2K.RESERVATIONS  
WHERE RENTAL_DETAILS_VW.USAGE_START_DATE = (
select max(case when ors2.USAGE_START_DATE is null 
    then {ts ' 2009-01-01 00:00:00 ' } 
    else ors2.USAGE_START_DATE END) 
FROM RENTAL_DETAILS_VW ors2 
where ors2.RESERVATION_ID=RESERVATIONS.RESERVATION_ID)
```

Comment: Please cut out extraneous fields to produce a minimal test case. Most of that doesn't matter for your question and I'm not looking forward to wading through it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for. It's also helpful if you could include some sample output - if possible, what you're actually seeing and what you'd like to see instead. Since we don't have your database, we can't tell what this is supposed to return.

Comment: @khoa: I've updated my answer with what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get any rows where USAGE_START_DATE is NULL because you're filtering them out - the WHERE clause at the end sees that only rows that have the max date for a matching RESERVATION_ID are included. Are you trying to include NULL USAGE_START_DATE rows, even if they don't have a matching reservation?

**UPDATE:** you don't need the DISTINCT, and it may negatively affect your results. Also, since you want a "Blank" instead of NULL, you'll need to use `ISNULL`. You'll need a `LEFT JOIN`, and I've also added some table aliases to make it a little easier to read. Here's what I think you want:

```
SELECT rd.RESERVATION_ID, 
       ISNULL(MAX(rd.USAGE_START_DATE), '') as START_DATE,
  FROM BYNXFLEET_BI.RENTAL_DETAILS_VW rd
  LEFT
  JOIN WILLOW2K.RESERVATIONS r
    ON rd.RESERVATION_ID = r.RESERVATION_ID
```